# Pass button information from multiple created buttons

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

I have a site that I would like to pass information using post.  The issue I am having is that I have a grid that dynamically fills out data according to a database and then creates buttons for each entry.  I would like each of these buttons to have separate functions, such as delete database entry, insert, or just a plain view of the full application.

This is what I have so far:

```
    @grid.GetHtml(    
        tableStyle : "grid",
        alternatingRowStyle : "alt",
        headerStyle : "header",
        columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column("AppId", "Action", format: @<text>
                            <button class="view-app display-mode" id="@item.AppId">View</button>
                            <button class="approve-app display-mode" id="@item.AppId">Approve</button>
                            <button class="deny-app display-mode" id="@item.AppId">Deny</button>
                            <button class="delete-app display-mode" id="@item.AppId">Delete</button>
                        </text>),
                 grid.Column("Name", "Name"), 
                 grid.Column("Class", "Class"), 
                 grid.Column("AppDate", "AppDate")
    )
   )
```

I know it will take javascript to get the id of the button pressed, so I also have this script, but cannot figure how to pass this back to the server from the client:

```
$(function () {
    $('.view-app').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parent('tr.first');
        var appId = $(this).prop("id");

    });
    $('.approve-app').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var appId = $(this).prop('id');

    });
    $('.deny-app').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parent('tr.first');
        var appId = $(this).prop("id");

    });
    $('.delete-app').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var appId = $(this).prop('id');

    });

})
```

Am I going about this wrong?  Is there some way that I can accomplish this that I haven't thought of?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each button a unique name and set the value to (insert|update|delete). This will post the  value of the button to the server-side with it's name as the key.

i.e...

```
<button class="view-app display-mode" id="@item.AppId" name="action_@item.AppId" value="view">View</button>
```

or

```
<button class="view-app display-mode" id="@item.AppId" name="view" value="@item.AppId">View</button>
```

Comment: Thank you.  As many buttons and textboxes I've made, and that just slipped my mind.  I took out the java and just did a IsPost statement using name and value.  Again thank you.